# mysql date convert error

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the below query that I am running in MySQL via an ODBC connection.

```
Select
PUB.oa_nltrans.company,
PUB.oa_nltrans.costcentre As Code,
PUB.oa_nltrans.docdate,

From
PUB.oa_nltrans 

Where
PUB.oa_nltrans.company = 01 And
(PUB.oa_nltrans.costcentre >= '14-01' And
PUB.oa_nltrans.costcentre <= '14-06') And
PUB.oa_nltrans.docdate = '31/08/2015'
```

I am trying to limit the date to 1 day  - 31/08/2015 but I am receiving an invalid date error.

The error I am getting is:

[image]

Can anyone advise on a way to use a convert in my query to be able to do this?

Many thanks,

Comment: please post the exact error

Answer (score 0):

Extra `,` in the select statement also.

```
SELECT PUB.oa_nltrans.company, PUB.oa_nltrans.costcentre As Code, PUB.oa_nltrans.docdate
FROM PUB.oa_nltrans 
WHERE PUB.oa_nltrans.company = 01 
AND PUB.oa_nltrans.costcentre BETWEEN '14-01' AND '14-06'
AND date_format(PUB.oa_nltrans.docdate, '%d/%m/%Y') = '31/08/2015'
```

A bit neater as you don't need to specify table when its the only table your selecting from.

```
SELECT company, costcentre AS Code, docdate
FROM PUB.oa_nltrans 
WHERE company = 01 
AND costcentre BETWEEN '14-01' AND '14-06'
AND date_format(docdate, '%d/%m/%Y') = '31/08/2015'
```

Comment: syntax error in sql statement at or about ") = '31/08/2015'" (10713)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming docdate is a DATE field in your table, and from the error your are getting it seems that the date format you are implying in your statement is wrongly format.

try using the default date format of a DATE field in MySQL which is YYYY-MM-DD. So your query should be:

```
Select
PUB.oa_nltrans.company,
PUB.oa_nltrans.costcentre As Code,
PUB.oa_nltrans.docdate,

From
PUB.oa_nltrans 

Where
PUB.oa_nltrans.company = 01 And
(PUB.oa_nltrans.costcentre >= '14-01' And
PUB.oa_nltrans.costcentre <= '14-06') And
PUB.oa_nltrans.docdate = '2015-08-31'
```